# Redirection to /dev/null block oggCat execution

Tags: ubuntu, ogg, ubuntu-13.10

I'm trying to use oggCat from another program, but when I call `oggCat output.ogv file1.ogv file2.ogv ... filex.ogv > /dev/null` the execution never ends.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oggCat might occasionaly block for user input, for example when output file already exists it will ask if you want to overwrite. Also note that oggCat output progress information on standard error, not standard output. And your program might not be executing via shell but directly, in which case '> /dev/null' won't work. Try to run it via:

```
sh -c 'oggCat -x bla.ogg 1*ogg < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

which should work around all the problems above. If it still doesn't work for you, you should find a process PID in `ps` output, and execute:

```
strace -ff -tt -p PID
```

to find out what program is doing (replace `PID` with PID of oggCat process)

Comment: It works! Thanks! As I'm calling from a java application, I use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791091/processbuilder-without-redirecting-stdout